# VertX JDBC with Strings to Varchar2

Tags: vert.x

I have a small table in Oracle for images and try to insert an image into the database (it is still Base64-Coded in the database).

```
 SQL> desc TEMP_IMAGES;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 UUID                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(64)
 IMAGE_CLOB                NOT NULL CLOB
 CREATION_DATE             NOT NULL DATE
```

And a not very complicate Store-Routine in VertX

```
public Future<String> storeImage(String image) {
    Promise<String> promise = Promise.promise();
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO TEMP_IMAGES (UUID, Image_Clob, Creation_Date ) VALUES (?, ?, sysdate)";
    this.pool
        .preparedQuery(sql)
        .execute(Tuple.of(uuid, image))
        .onSuccess( succ -> promise.complete(uuid) )
        .onFailure( err  -> promise.fail(err) );
    return promise.future();
}
```

In this case, the JDBC returns:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-17004: Invalid column type
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8341) ~[ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar:23.2.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:7819) ~[ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar:23.2.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8580) ~[ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar:23.2.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObject(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8561) ~[ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar:23.2.0.0.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:219) ~[ojdbc8-23.2.0.0.jar:23.2.0.0.0]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setObject(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:821) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.5.jar:0.9.5.5]
        at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.fillStatement(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:142) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
        at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.execute(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:63) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
        at io.vertx.jdbcclient.impl.actions.JDBCPreparedQuery.execute(JDBCPreparedQuery.java:44) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
        at io.vertx.ext.jdbc.impl.JDBCConnectionImpl.lambda$schedule$3(JDBCConnectionImpl.java:219) ~[vertx-jdbc-client-4.4.0.jar:4.4.0]
```

If I replace the UUID-Parameter within the sql-stmt everything is fine:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO TEMP_IMAGES (UUID, Image_Clob, Creation_Date ) VALUES ('"+uuid+"', ?, sysdate)";
```

Same issue on VertX 4.4.6, same issue if I use a different column-name, it seems it is related to the Oracle-Type VARCHAR2(xx).

I don't see, that I made any mistake on the Tuple-Parameter-Setting.

Comment: Even execute(Tuple.of(“…uuid String …”, image)) is not working.

Comment: I think the issue is with the `clob` column not the `uuid`

Comment: No it is the uuid. I tried without the clob and it fails, too. If you use VALUES ("blablabla", ?, sysdate)" it works fine. The clob is stored into the database. If I make only an insert with the uuid (nothing else), it failes too.